# Why does my Julia profiler result show so much compilation load?

Tags: optimization, julia, profiling

I am profiling some Julia code in the process of optimizing it for speed.  The profiler results show that a large amount of time is spent on a particular function call.  The call looks roughly like this:

```
my_function!( view(x,ind_x), view(y,ind_y), a, b, c )
```

where `a`, `b`, are `c` are `Float64`s, `x` and `y` are vector views into a 2D array of `Float64`s passed in from elsewhere, and `ind_x` and `ind_y` are ranges.  The function itself selects other functions to call based on the length of the 2 views that are passed in and has the following form:

```
function my_function!( X::AbstractVector, Y::AbstractVector, a, b, c )
  if length( X ) == 6
    do_stuff_A!( view( X, 1:2 ), a, c^2, view( Y, 1:2 ) )
    do_stuff_B_4!( view( X, 3:6 ), a, b^2, view( Y, 3:6 ) )
  elseif length( X ) == 8
    do_stuff_A!( view( X, 1:2 ), a, c^2, view( Y, 1:2 ) )
    do_stuff_B_6!( view( X, 3:8 ), a, b^2, view( Y, 3:8 ) )
  elseif length( X ) == 2
    do_stuff_A!( X, a, c^2, Y )
  else
    error( "Incorrect input size!" )
  end

  return nothing
end
```

The `do_stuff_*` functions modify the 1st argument in place.  They are straightforward math: some coefficients are calculated based on the scalar arguments and some matrix multiplications are performed.  StaticArrays types are used.

I am using the `@profview` macro in VSCode.  The macro is set at a loop that contain calls that reach `my_function!` a few levels down.  The loop is in a script that gets called as `include("my_script.jl")` in the Julia REPL.  The results are shown in VSCode's own flame graph.

Based on what the `do_stuff_*` functions do and how much they get called, it is not surprising to me that `my_function!` would feature prominently in the profiler results as it does but none of the samples point to anything actually inside the function.  All the traces that run through this function are flagged as "compilation."  Here is a flame graph excerpt:

[image: Flame Graph Sample]

I ran the profiler a few times to make sure I'm not getting faulty results from compilation at a first run.  The first pass has more time devoted to this call but the following runs still have a significant amount.

What does this mean?  Why does the call to this function seem to spend more time on compilation than the actual math?

**Edit:**  I have since run the code with a 10 times longer loop and the results make more sense so it was probably largely a matter of there not being enough samples.  However, there are still a few deep columns of compilation-flagged traces even after the 1st run-through.  There are not many paths in the code and I did my best to keep things type-stable.  Why is there so much compilation?

Comment: `@code_warntype` on `my_function!` should tell you where the type stability problem is.

Comment: @Oscar Smith Do you think it's a type stability problem based on the profiler results?

Comment: I don't know (the problem is somewhere in the `do_stuff` functions), but `@code_warntype` will tell you.